# How to test Zentasks sample app from Play 2.0

Tags: scala, testing, playframework-2.0

I play with Play 2.0, Scala version. Currently, I analyze [Zentasks sample app](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/tree/master/samples/scala/zentasks).

One of the part of this app is authentication mechanism mostly covered in `Secured` trait. I'm wondering how I can test secured actions, ex. `index` from [Projects controller](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/master/samples/scala/zentasks/app/controllers/Projects.scala).

For not-secured action, I'd probably do something like

```
val result = controllers.Projects.index(FakeRequest())
```

to run an action and get its result.

What should I do in case of the secured action?

*Disclaimer*: I'm totally new to both Scala and Play, so all hints are very valuable. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There is a [fix for the integrated approach to this](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/commit/818025bbd) in Playframewrk v2.1 I have a [backport of the fix on the 2.0.x branch](https://github.com/jeantil/Play20/commit/651b431fefe8365fd48d73fc495e362ef1ee3781)

Until it gets merged and released, here is what I did (it works on Play 2.0.3+):

I defined my own Helpers object in a libs package like so.

```
package libs

import play.api.mvc._

import play.api.libs.iteratee._
import play.api.libs.concurrent._
import play.api.test._

object Helpers {

  def routeAndCall[T](request: FakeRequest[T]): Option[Result] = {
    routeAndCall(this.getClass.getClassLoader.loadClass("Routes").asInstanceOf[Class[play.core.Router.Routes]], request)
  }
  /**
   * Use the Router to determine the Action to call for this request and executes it.
   */
  def routeAndCall[T, ROUTER <: play.core.Router.Routes](router: Class[ROUTER], request: FakeRequest[T]): Option[play.api.mvc.Result] = {
    val routes = router.getClassLoader.loadClass(router.getName + "$").getDeclaredField("MODULE$").get(null).asInstanceOf[play.core.Router.Routes]
    routes.routes.lift(request).map {
      case a: Action[_] =>
        val action = a.asInstanceOf[Action[T]]
        val parsedBody: Option[Either[play.api.mvc.Result, T]] = action.parser(request).fold(
          (a, in) => Promise.pure(Some(a)),
          k => Promise.pure(None),
          (msg, in) => Promise.pure(None)
        ).await.get

        parsedBody.map{resultOrT =>
          resultOrT.right.toOption.map{innerBody =>
            action(FakeRequest(request.method, request.uri, request.headers, innerBody))
          }.getOrElse(resultOrT.left.get)
        }.getOrElse(action(request))
    }
  }

}
```

Then in my test I import my Helpers and the whole play Helpers context, except for routeAndCall :

```
import libs.Helpers._
import play.api.test.Helpers.{routeAndCall => _,_}
```

I then use an Around to setup my app (I need the provide an application.secret as I store the authenticated user name in the session which is based on a signed cookie)

```
def appWithSecret():Map[String,String]={
    Map(("application.secret","the answer is 42 !"))
  }


  object emptyApp extends Around {
    def around[T <% Result](t: => T) = {
      running(FakeApplication(additionalConfiguration = inMemoryMongoDatabase("emptyApp")++appWithSecret())) {
        User(new ObjectId, "Jane Doe", "foobar@example.com", "id1").save()
        t // execute t inside a http session
      }
    }
  }
```

This allows me to write the following tests:

```
"respond to the index Action" in emptyApp {
      val request: FakeRequest[AnyContent] = FakeRequest(GET, "/expenses").withSession(("email", "foobar@example.com"))
      val Some(result) = routeAndCall(request)

      status(result) must equalTo(OK)
      contentType(result) must beSome("application/json")
      charset(result) must beSome("utf-8")
      contentAsString(result) must contain("Hello Bob")
    }
```

It allows you to exercise the secured code even though it is not a unit test.

Answer (score 1):

ok, I am no great expert either, but here is an idea.

Create a `trait InSecure trait extends Secured` which overrides the Secured actions and always permits access.
Then you can make an `object InSecureProjects extends Projects with InSecture` in your test, this should override just the security checks and let you test the actions without any security.

Now, instead of running the tests on `Projects`, you run them on `InSecureProjects`. You can do exactly the same for the other secured controllers.

I haven't tested it, so let me know if it works ;)